# searchAfter in lucene

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I am trying out a deep search in lucene for my resources.

```
        Query q1 = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] { "products",
                "name"}, analyzer).parse(queryStr1);
        Query q2 = new TermQuery(new Term("keywords", queryStr2));
        IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(indexLocation);
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(ir);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(
                reqHits, true);

        is.search(q1, collector);
        ScoreDoc results[] = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        TopDocs topDocs = null;
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : results) {
            topDocs = is.searchAfter(scoreDoc, q2, 1);
        }
        ScoreDoc deepResults[] = topDocs.scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < deepResults.length; i++) {
            Document doc = is.doc(deepResults[i].doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get("name"));
        }
```

searchAfter() can be applied on scoreDocs of a previous search.But it requires scoreDoc as the first parameter, so I loop inorder to achieve the individual scoreDoc. I am not sure how we can apply the afterSearch to get the results as expected since my code doesnt give me expected results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean to accomplish.  Are you trying to search with `q1`, and then search within the returned result set for docs matching `q2`?

Comment: yes.That was what I tried to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to search for results of `q2` within the results of `q1`.

The simplest, is just combine the two queries with a boolean query:

```
BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
finalQuery.add(q1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
finalQuery.add(q2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
is.search(finalQuery, collector);
```

Even if your use case is to get and display results from `q1`, and then take `q2` as input from the user, and run another search, keeping `q1`, and generating a `BooleanQuery` as the the final query remains a good approach.

You could also use a `Filter` for one of the queries.  This is particularly useful if one of them, say `q1`, is a query you expect to reuse frequently, and would benefit from caching the results of it, such as:

```
Filter q1Filter = new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(q1));
is.search(q2, q1Filter, collector);
```

Comment: Got it!. I got confused with the usage of searchAfter() and was trying to achieve my use case using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong usage of `searchAfter`. The idea is to make one search with an upper bound on the result size, then repeat the search with `searchAfter`, passing the *last* scoreDoc from the previous result, so you get the next "result page". This is how Lucene supports unbounded result set sizes.